# Want to remove extraneous markup from highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Really diving into Highcharts hard and deep (on a time crunch, of course) and I've hit a few spots that are just utterly frustrating. Case in point, tooltips always seem to be generated with a nested `<span>` with a bunch of inline styles. That span is getting in the way of me properly formatting the tooltip with CSS.

Here's the code that's being spit out:

```
<div class="highcharts-tooltip" style="position: absolute; left: 499px; top: 34px; opacity: 1; visibility: visible;"><span style="position: absolute; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 8px; top: 8px;" zindex="1">Content (this is all I want inside the DIV... not the span surrounding it)</span></div>
```

Here are the tooltip settings from the script generating the chart the tooltip is part of:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
     headerFormat: '',
     useHTML: true,
     formatter: function () {
         return this.y;
     },
     positioner: function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
         return {
             x: point.plotX + boxWidth,
             y: boxHeight
         };
     }
 }
```

What's the best way to eliminate that span (while retaining the content it's wrapped around)?

Comment: Let me know why you need to remove that span? How your tooltip should does it look like? Always you can overwrite inline styles by CSS styles.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: I'd like to remove it to simplify the code. Sure, I could do all sorts of things with jQuery and other things to override and rewrite it... but the simple solution **should** be to just prevent unnecessary code from showing up in the first place.

When all's said and done it should just be:
`<div class="highcharts-tooltip" style="position: absolute; left: 499px; top: 34px; opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">Content</div>`

Comment: I would like to know why you need to remove span, in other words what this span breaks in your tooltip? It will be helpful for understand and find any other solution.

Comment: @SebastianBochan The absolute positioning and other associated inline styles on that SPAN get in the way of the styles I want to trickle down from the overall ToolTip div. I'm trying to avoid extraneous code and extra overrides. The goal is for the text to be centered in the overall DIV, not up in the corner of it, and to properly take the text styling that's standard on the rest of the page.

Comment: You can disable default tooltip, create your own in HTML / CSS. Then catch mouseOver / mouseOut events to print tooltip in right place. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b9hk96kz/

Comment: @SebastianBochan So you're saying there is no way to prevent the script from generating that interior span that is easier than building my own tooltip code from scratch?

Comment: You can wrap the Highcharts function and develop own code or use my solution from previous post. I think that is simpler.